# Pandas dataframe is filled with "NaN", not correct values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I'm trying to reformat a pandas dataframe, like shown below.  However, NaN's appear instead ofthe values from the original data frame. 
Code:
`df = df.T.reindex(subjects)`

From this:

```
                        rating_per_subject
1  {'P1': **4**, 'P2': **1**, 'T1': **2**, 'S1': **5**, 'S2': **5**, ...
2  {'P1': 1, 'P2': 1, 'T1': 5, 'S1': 1, 'S2': 1, ...
3  {'P1': 3, 'P2': 2, 'T1': 4, 'S1': 5, 'S2': 4, ...
4  {'P1': 2, 'P2': 5, 'T1': 5, 'S1': 4, 'S2': 5, ...
```

To this format:

```
      1      2    3     4
P1  **NaN**  NaN  NaN  NaN
P2  **NaN**  NaN  NaN  NaN
T1  **NaN**  NaN  NaN  NaN
S1  **NaN**  NaN  NaN  NaN
S2  **NaN**  NaN  NaN  NaN
R1  **NaN**  NaN  NaN  NaN
R2  **NaN**  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: could you please add some code  in the question?

Comment: What is the content of *subjects*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create your source DataFrame, I:

1. Created the following list of dictionaries:

   ```
   tbl = [ {'P1': '**4**', 'P2': '**1**', 'T1': '**2**', 'S1': '**5**', 'S2': '**5**'},
           {'P1':    1,    'P2':    1,    'T1':    5,    'S1':    1,    'S2':    1},
           {'P1':    3,    'P2':    2,    'T1':    4,    'S1':    5,    'S2':    4},
           {'P1':    2,    'P2':    5,    'T1':    5,    'S1':    4,    'S2':    5}]
   ```

   Note that values in the first row are enclosed in quotes (a differnce to your sample),
   otherwise there would be invalid syntax.
2. Created the DataFrame:

   ```
   df = pd.DataFrame({'rating_per_subject': tbl})
   ```

Note that so far your DataFrame contains a **single** column.
But as your code contains invocation of `T` attribute (a transformation),
the source DataFrame should be of "true-2D" shape, i.e. it should contain
**multiple** rows and columns.

In my opinion, the missing step is to break down each row into columns, i.e.
dictionary keys should be converted to column names and dictionary values - to
column values.

You can do it executing:

```
df2 = df.rating_per_subject.apply(pd.Series)
```

what gives:

```
      P1     P2     T1     S1     S2
0  **4**  **1**  **2**  **5**  **5**
1      1      1      5      1      1
2      3      2      4      5      4
3      2      5      5      4      5
```

Now, when you transpose this DataFrame (run `df2.T`), you will get:

```
        0  1  2  3
P1  **4**  1  3  2
P2  **1**  1  2  5
T1  **2**  5  4  5
S1  **5**  1  5  4
S2  **5**  1  4  5
```

Assume that `subjects = ['P1', 'P2', 'T1', 'S1', 'S2', 'R1', 'R2']`.

When you run `df2.T.reindex(subjects)`, you will get:

```
        0    1    2    3
P1  **4**    1    3    2
P2  **1**    1    2    5
T1  **2**    5    4    5
S1  **5**    1    5    4
S2  **5**    1    4    5
R1    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
R2    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

Comment: You are right! By breaking down each row into columns I got the expected result. Thank you.